# Python Selenium - element is not attached to the page document

Tags: python, parsing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to parse Facebook fan page likers and get exception in line

```
driver.get("{}".format(url.get_attribute("href")))
```

> selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message:
>   stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

when program switched to second element of loop

```
#coding: utf-8
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
import random
from PIL import Image
import csv
import string
import re

opts = Options()
opts.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36")
#driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/sweeetopium/PycharmProjects/education_py/education_py/chromedriver', chrome_options=opts)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/kr/PycharmProjects/education_py/chromedriver',chrome_options=opts)


user_login = ''
user_pass = ''

def login_to_fb():
    driver.set_window_size(1280,800)
    driver.get("https://facebook.com/login/")
    driver.find_element_by_id('email').send_keys(user_login)
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_id('pass').send_keys(user_pass)
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.find_element_by_id('loginbutton').send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/page")
    time.sleep(15)
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').click()
    time.sleep(5)
    for i in xrange(10):
        driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
        time.sleep(1)
        print(i)
    time.sleep(10)
    all_likes_urls = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, '/ufi/')]")
    return all_likes_urls

def open_post_likes():
    all_likers = []
    for url in login_to_fb():
        time.sleep(10)
        driver.get("{}".format(url.get_attribute("href")))
        print("ok1")
        time.sleep(5)
        driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body").click()
        time.sleep(2)
        print("ok2")
        likers = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[contains(@class, 'uiList')]/li/div/ul/li/div/a")
        print("ok3")
        for liker in likers:
            print liker.get_attribute("href")
    return all_likers

print open_post_likes()
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are no longer on the same page after you navigate to another page in the for loop. This should be resolved if you navigate back to the original page where you fetched the `all_likes_urls` from at the end of each iteartion of the for loop i.e.

```
def open_post_likes():
    all_likers = []
    for url in login_to_fb():
        time.sleep(10)
        driver.get("{}".format(url.get_attribute("href")))
        print("ok1")
        time.sleep(5)
        driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body").click()
        time.sleep(2)
        print("ok2")
        likers = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[contains(@class, 'uiList')]/li/div/ul/li/div/a")
        print("ok3")
        for liker in likers:
            print liker.get_attribute("href")
    driver.back()   ##go back to the previous page
    ## driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/page")  ## Or go to the original page where u fetched urls from 
    return all_likers
```